# Encryption (Symmetric key) lib

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, symmetric-key

I have been reading a little bit about Encryption.

I'm currently in a project where I'll need to Encrypt/Decrypt data based on a key (user password), but the problem is:
 - I'll need to encrypt/decrypt in several client applications built with different languages. Example:
   - PHP
   - C++
   - Java
etc.

What should I do? is there any good (and free) lib that was written to different languages?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have one-and-the-same-lib for different platforms...

as long as the choosen ciphers & keys & modes of operation are the same, it shouldn't really matter.

for example i've had no problems with AES encrypting in c# using the crypto service provider which ships with the .net framework and decrypting using the openssl module for php ...

there sometimes are some hurdles, like byteorder, encoding, etc. but if you take a closer look there's no black magic ...